# Store Firebase Data as JSON locally

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I want to use JSON as a local database for my firebase data ,I don't want offline data store.I am using path_provider to store my data on the phone

So I tried storing data with

```
file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(snapshot.toString()))
```

And it worked the stored data file looked like a JSON file

```
"{-key:{name:name,age:age},-key:{name:name,age:age}}"
```

The " " where missing and I can't decode it.
So what can be done here ? 
(Edit:Does Firestore provide anything that can help me with this ?)

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the String yourself?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot  I tried rebuilding the JSON and storing it but I don't think I implemented that properly, it added '/' after every key and value.
I can't seem to get JSON working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a JSON File

```
 Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }


  Future<File> get _dbFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return new File("$path/demo.json");
  }
```

Write data into a file

```
  Future<File> write(DataSnapshot snapshot,String chatId) async {
    final path = await _dbFile;
    final String key = snapshot.key;
    final String name = snapshot.value['senderUid'];
    final int age= snapshot.value['receivedUid'];
    String content = '{"$key":{"name":"$name","age":"$age"}}';
    return file.writeAsStringSync(content);
  }
```

Read Data

```
  Future<Null> read() async {
    try {
      final file = await _dbFile;
      String content = file.readAsStringSync();
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMap=json.decode(content);
      chatMap.keys.forEach((E){debugPrint(E);});
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error : '+e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) package to store JSON, 
or if you want to write to a custom file use the [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) package to get paths to directories where you app has permissions to write to.

You might also need to use the async versions of the `dart:io` API to access files in Flutter (not sure about that tough)

`"{-key:{name:name,age:age},-key:{name:name,age:age}}"` is not valid JSON

Either use

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
var myJson = {'-key':{'name:name','age:age'},'-key':{'name:name','age:age'}}";
var myJsonString = jsonEncode(myJson);
await file.writeAsString(myJsonString);
```

or

```
var myJsonString = '{"-key":{"name:name","age:age"},"-key":{"name:name","age:age"}}';
await file.writeAsString(myJsonString);
```

Comment: That was the problem , the data I got when I toString() the DataSnapshot return of Firebase was not a valid JSON. I tried to encode the firebase data into JSON with String content = '{"$key":{"name:$name","age:$age"}}'; await file.writeAsString(content); That works , I have not tried serializing it yet but syncing file writes with firebase database stream would that be a problem easier to solve ?

Comment: That's already a string. Not sure what you would serialize that to. I also don't understand what you mean with "syncing file writes with firebase database". I don't know about such a functionality.

Comment: By serializing I mean this [link]( https://flutter.io/json/) and by syncing file I mean, when I call firebase with lets say onChildAdded,the files need to be written every time that happens and still be a valid JSON. Now I am starting to think storing JSON like this is good.

Comment: `String content = '...'` as you have it in the first comment above is already encoded. With Firebase you'd use a Map instead like in the code block below "Either use" in my answer. What you get from Firebase is a Map as well and this needs to be encoded before written to a file.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you,I posted the answer with both read and write. I knew I can create a JSON string and store it  I wanted to manipulate the map as such that it is encoded into JSON .